# is accessing a raw resource from within android library possible?

Tags: android, resources

I am writing an android library and am having a problem.

In my library I am attempting to access a file stored in the `res/raw` directory of my library project like that:

```
InputStream inputStream = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.sample);
```

I've also tried:

`InputStream inputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample);` (where mContext is a reference I've passed from my main app to my library)

However I get an exception `file not found` when trying to instantiate my library from my main project.

Is it possible to actually do this, and if so how do I go about doing it? or do I need to pull in the resource from my main project and send it to the library?

Answer (score 1):

Accesing a raw resource located in some app from your library is bad design.

I suggest opening first the `InputStream` in your application, using the second syntax you posted. Then pass the InputStream to your library.

If you finally decide to access the resource from your library, you could try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication%28java.lang.String%29).