# Android - access app resources from a library or pass them through two intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, shared-libraries, android-resources

I have a library that is to be used by three apps.

In each of the three apps you can click various buttons, in Activity A which will load Activity B in the library.

In Activity B you click on a button and are taken to Activity C.

In Activity C i wish to be able to access a hashmap that is created in the local app from a json file in the raw folder of that local app.

Can i just access the json file from within the library, if say, i give them all the same name?

If not, is the correct procedure to pass from activity A to B to C? Seems a bit over the top.

The question below seems to say direct access is a bad idea but it seems much preferable to passing data between two activities that don't use it.

[is accessing a raw resource from within android library possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649317/is-accessing-a-raw-resource-from-within-android-library-possible)

Comment: if your data is stored as a raw resource of your main app, I don't think your library will have access to it by default. You'll have to pass it to those activities as an extra on the intent that you use to launch them I think.

Comment: Foamguy, yeah that's what I'm currently doing. Just seems very long winded to do it that way.

Comment: Well, there certainly are other ways you could achieve it. A ContentProvider springs to mind as one candidate. Honestly though as long winded as it may be, I think it is really your easiest most straight forward option.

Comment: I will do a content provider eventually but don't have the time to learn all about them just yet. I need to get this thing done and out the door then once it is i can go back and switch it over to a content provider at a later date. Though can my library read from a content provider setup in the native app?

Comment: I worded my last comment poorly. What I meant was that I think the way that you are doing it (passing the data along as an extra on the intent) is actually the easiest way. ContentProvider is technically another way that you could do it, but it is probably even more convoluted than what you are doing now.

Comment: Really? I think that passing it through 3 intents through 3 activities is a really convoluted way. I can't understand why I can't just access the json file from within the library. That would make so much more sense